# Rails: returning a controller object to AJAX caller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am calling a Rails controller using AJAX, pulling a record, and then returning that record to the AJAX call. My AJAX request is as follows (I'm using CoffeScript):

```
jQuery ->
  $.ajax
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/reports',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: (response) ->
      console.log response
      return
    error: (response) ->
      console.log response
      return
```

My controller is the following:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def report
    @test_result = TestResult.first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: @test_result.to_json }
      format.html
    end
  end

end
```

Now, I can access the object in AJAX but through the error function (`error: (response) ->`) not the success function (`success: (response)->`) of the AJAX method. How come the response is not going to the success function, even when the status from the xhr call is 200 or ok? I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the AJAX call with `dataType: 'json'` and return `format.json` with status code along your AJAX response from the controller.

```
jQuery ->
  $.ajax
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/reports',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: (response) ->
      console.log response
      return
    error: (response) ->
      console.log response
      return
```

Controller

```
def report
  @test_result = TestResult.first

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @test_result.to_json, status: :success }
    format.html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL in ajax config should be `'/reports/report'`, because  The URL in Ajax  is `'/controller/action'`  and try with `dataType: 'json'`, because this is what you are specting from server.

Answer (score 1):

I made my own solution. I hope it can helps you.

=== Controller

```
def show
    @type = Type.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @type.to_json, status: 200 }
      format.html
    end
  end
```

=== Coffee file

```
type_changed = (id) ->
  $.ajax
    type: 'GET'
    , url: "/types/#{id}"
    success: (data) ->
      console.log('Success')
      console.log(data)
      return
    error: (data) ->
      console.log('Error')
      console.log(data)
      return
```